# how to make one control to show a property of any derived class in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

this might be a easy question but I am struggling with it.

I have two classes that are derived from a base class

```
class Base
{
  public int BaseProperty;
  ...
}

class A: Base
{
public int Property_derived;
...
}

Class B: Base
{
public int Property_derived;
...
}
```

Now I have a UI form, that got a textbox that should display the property of derived class(I assure the number and datatypes of properties of all derived classes would be same)
I have done something like:

```
textbox1.text = objectA.Property_derived;
```

how do I change it to make it more generic like:

```
textbox1.text = objecttypedoesntmatter.Property_derived;
```

so that I should be able to use the same user interface for any derived class.
Any help much appreciated.
Many Thanks

Comment: But ... the object type *does* matter. `A.Property_derived` is declared in `A`, so you have to ensure that the object you are accessing is of type `A`. You say "any derived class" - *what* derived class? A subclass of `A`? Can you provide an example?

Comment: This sounds like a job for an `interface`, to me. Possibly an `abstract class`, but more likely an `interface`

Comment: @Mapper: my apologies, 'any derived class' here mean either A or B
for eg. I am looking to use, ObjectofA.Property_derived or ObjectofB.Property_derived, without making any hardcoded statements like, A ObjectofA = new A()

Comment: @Avais: Have a look at Oren's response then and use interfaces. Note that, unless you refactor your code so `Property_derived` is actually described in `Base`, as suggested by Avner, you can use interfaces, at which point it is actually irrelevant whether your class `A` and `B` also have a common base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is define your Property_derived in the base class, and thus have it as part of the shared contract of all derived classes. Polymorphism, a property of inheritance, will call  the derived, overridden property. Note, though, that this will work for a *property*, not a field:

```
class Base
{
   public virtual int MyProperty {get { return 1;} }   
}

class A: Base
{
   public override int MyProperty { get { return 5; } }
}

class B: Base
{
   public override int MyProperty { get { retun 7; } }
}
```

Comment: my first question on stackoverflow, loved the response.
EDIT: Thanks a lot :)